# MongoDB per message TTL

Tags: mongodb, go, nosql, ttl

Is it possible to set the TTL per message in MongoDB? I want to insert messages that can have different TTL's and I use MongoDB to check if I have to resend a message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, see [Expire Data from Collections by Setting TTL](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/).

First you have to create a TTL index where you set `0` for `expireAfterSeconds`. And you have to set the `expireAt` timestamp, calculated by adding the wished TTL to the current time.

E.g. create an index:

```
db.log_events.createIndex( { "expireAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 } )
```

And then if you want 3 seconds TTL for a document, insert it with a property:

```
"expireAt": time.Now().Add(3 * time.Second)
```

To have a document with 1 hour TTL:

```
"expireAt": time.Now().Add(time.Hour)
```